# Galois group of polynomial over rational functions

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, rational-functions, splitting-field

Let $F = \mathbb Q(y)$ be a field of rational functions, and $F[x]$ be polynomial ring over it.

How do I show that $f(x) = x^n - y$ is irreducible for a natural number $n$, and find a splitting field and a Galois group of $f$?

Comment: Use Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: Oh, so since y is not a square, it follows from Eisenstein that f is irreducible? What about the remaining parts?

Comment: Splitting field $\mathbb Q(y^{1/n},e^{2\pi i/n})$. Calculate the Galois group yourself.